# Using --prefix when upgrading python packages

Tags: python, installation, pip

The `--prefix` option to `setup.py` (and `pip` via `--install-option`) seems broken.

I need to maintain a shared repository of updated python packages on a machine where I do not have `sudo` access.   Theoretically the `--prefix` option to `setup.py` (and pip the via `--install-option`) can do what I need.

However if there is already a version of the package I am installing in the system directories, I cannot install it on my private repository.  Installing without `--upgrade` fails because a package already exists in the system, and installing with `--upgrade` fails because the old package version cannot be removed.   This is shown in the error message below.

Is there any way to prevent install from trying to remove the old version of a package?  OR, more likely, am I just not understanding how this is supposed to work?

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

$ pip install  -U --install-option="--prefix=/python-local" virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c2aa2fc4986967815f8cb3a3418e6031
  Downloading virtualenv-1.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
  Found existing installation: virtualenv 1.7.1.2
    Uninstalling virtualenv:
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1431, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 598, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1836, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/python-local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 295, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/virtualenv'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/user/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use pip's `--ignore-installed` option.   You must use this option whenever a read-only version of the package you are installing is visible in the current environment.  This includes when using `--user`, `--local`, or `--prefix`, and also if you are installing into a virtualenv that was created with  `--system-site-packages`

You can find this option mentioned at the very end of this section http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#user-installs
or with `pip install --help`